# Basic python tic tac toe: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Tags: python

I'm new to this, but I'm trying to make tic-tac-toe in python and following this instructional video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2o8ckO-lfk&t=1777s). I've tried to make sense of it and checked with the source code for some time now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It isn't finished yet, but there shouldn't be an error coming out in the terminal right now if I was doing it right. The error says "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list." I've put arrows by the lines that Replit is saying is causing it. Thanks!!

```
board = [
  ["-", "-", "-"],
  ["-", "-", "-"],
  ["-", "-", "-"]
]

def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    for slot in row:
      print(f"{slot} ", end = "")
    print()

def quit(user_input):
  if user_input.lower() == "q": 
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    return True
  else: return False


def check_input(user_input):
  #check if it's a number
  if not isnum(user_input): return False
  user_input = int(user_input)
  #check if it's 1 - 9
  if not bounds(user_input): return False

  return True

def isnum(user_input):
  if not user_input.isnumeric():
    print("This is not a valid number")
    return False
  else: return True

def bounds(user_input):
  if user_input > 9 or user_input < 1:
    print("This number is not 1 - 9.")
    return False
  else: return True

def istaken(coords,board):
  row = coords[0]
  col = [1]
  if board[row][col] != "-":   <------------
    print("Something's already there.")
    return True
  else: return False

def coordinates(user_input):
  row = int(user_input / 3)
  col = user_input
  if col > 2: col = int(col % 3)
  return (row,col)

def add_to_board(coords, board):
  row = coords[0]
  col = coords[1]
  board[row][col] = "x"


while True:
  print_board(board)
  user_input = input("Please enter a position 1-9 or enter \"q\" to quit:")
  if quit(user_input): break
  if not check_input(user_input):
    print("Please try again.")
    continue
  user_input = int(user_input) - 1
  coords = coordinates(user_input)
  if istaken(coords,board):     <------------
    print("Please try again.")
    continue
```

Comment: If `col = [1]` then isn't `board[row][col]` the same as `board[row][[1]]` ?-- why the double brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

Line 43. You are assigning in your namespace the variable `col` to reference value [1]. In other words `col` points to a data structure that is a list with one element: integer 1.

Line 44. You use this list to pass it as an index to the 2D list. Indices for lists have to be integers (aka 0, 1, 2 in your case). Hence, the exception `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"`

What you're looking to do is:
`col = coords[1]` for line 43

I tested it and it works. However you have other issues you have to debug beyond that point. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
col = [1]
```

to

```py
col = coords[1]
```